# pdf is getting corrupted while sending from javax.mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am creating a pdf using Itext, after creating I am sending it in a mail by converting it into byte[]
I am able to generate the byte[] and also check by online tool pdf, they are able to generate pdf from my byte[] 
but when I send this byte[] from my java code the file gets corrupted.

Below is my code

This is the half part where I am converting pdf into byte[]

```
document.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
System.out.println("Done");
sendEmail(bytes);
```

And from here I am sending mail

```
public static void sendEmail(byte[] pdf) throws IOException {
          System.out.println("Starte");
          System.out.println(new String(pdf));
        final String username = "b*****@gmail.com";
        final String password = "*****";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("*****@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("******@gmail.com, *****@gmail.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail SSL");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!");


            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); //1
         // Create the attachment part
         BodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); //2
         attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(pdf,"application/pdf"))); //2
         attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("Hello.pdf"); // 2
         multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart); //3
         // Create the HTML Part
         BodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); //4
         htmlBodyPart.setContent("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                 + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!" , "text/html"); //5
         multipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart); // 6
         // Set the Multipart's to be the email's content
         message.setContent(multipart); //7


            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Please let me know what is the issue with the code
Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert it to Base64?

Comment: i don't want to save file in file system, also its not base64 actually its byte[] which I am using

Comment: "also its not base64 actually its byte[] which I am using" - but you've base64 encoded it: `bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);` - again, are you sure you want to do that? It's not clear to me that you should, although it's been a while since I've used JavaMail.

Comment: @xtratic i got the solution. thanks for pointing me out.
I was using this line `bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);` to convert it into base64 which was causing issue.

Comment: As I suspected. Glad we could help. Sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes to help catch those little things.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct I dont need this line `bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);`